# VPN Tunneling using WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF Service using http protocol. How do I convert my WCF service to make use of VPN.

Are ther some kind of changes that I have to make. Also could someone point me to some basic introductory stuffs related to VPN tunneling and WCF.

may be this question is pretty abstract. but pls excuse.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VPN is a Network, not a Protocol.

The only thing you can do is open a VPN Tunnel to your VPN Network where the WCF Service is hosted (For example with Cisco VPN Client or Shrew VPN). Then you can access your WCF Service within the VPN Network, everything will be sent over the VPN Tunnel, doesn't matter if HTTP, HTTPS, in the end it's TCP/UDP..

If you want to secure your WCF Messages, go for HTTPS, Certificate, etc.